# Moving specific cell data to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move specific data "1" & "2" from one cell to another and I am having trouble with the code. The cell data moves but I keep getting "false" instead of the data moving. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

[image]

```
Sub tested()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lrow As Integer, irow As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For Each rng In .Range("A1:A" & lrow)
            If InStr(rng.Value, "1") > 0 Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value = rng.Value = ""
            End If
        Next rng

        irow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For Each rng In .Range("A1:A" & lrow)
            If InStr(rng.Value, "2") > 0 Then
                rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = rng.Value = rng.Value = ""
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
```

Comment: Note that you only need one loop to do this. `irow` is equal to `lrow`. You could move the 2nd `If...End If` into the first loop, or use `Select Case` to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the lines where you have this:

```
rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value = rng.Value = ""
```

to this

```
rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value
```

New code:

```
Sub tested()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lrow As Integer, irow As Integer

    With ActiveSheet

        lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each rng In .Range("A1:A" & lrow)

            If InStr(rng.Value, "1") > 0 Then

                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value
                rng.ClearContents

            ElseIf InStr(rng.Value, "2") > 0 Then

                rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = rng.Value
                rng.ClearContents

            End If

        Next rng

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, how can I move 1 & 2, instead of duplicating them?

Comment: @JonathanLoresco add a `rng.ClearContents` or use [`Range.Cut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut).